# Add strings from the Review Queue stat page into transifex to make it possible to translate for Stackexchange localized sites

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, localization, transifex

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/stats

> [image]

Strings:

1. Admin.
2. Advanced stats.
3. Audits.
4. Bans.

Could you add those strings into transifex, so we will be able to translate them?